# Map format for a 3D game

Tags: c#, xna, format

I'm learning 3D programming and I decided to make a really simple "engine" where you can just fly around the map, etc. Only basic rendering of walls.

So, I was thinking - how can I save the level and how can I edit it. I don't want to make also an editor for it, because it is only a learning project, and not an actual game. So, I was looking towards this level format: UDMF http://zdoom.org/wiki/Universal_Doom_Map_Format although it is for a completely different type of game, still, it does what I need. Specifies vertices, floor, ceiling positions, etc. So, basic 2.5D geometry, which could be easily interpreted into a 3D space, which is more than enough for my purposes. There are also tons of editors (main reason).

BUT, I do realise that this is not really the best solution, and kind of workaround.

**So, my question:** Is there any "open" map format and "open" editors that I can use for my engine/game?

UPD: I'm working with C# and XNA, if that is important.

Answer (score 3):

You could use XML (or something even simpler) that provides the location and other attributes of all the objects in the level. This would be the easiest solution (and have the benefit of containing whatever info *you* want but nothing else) but would not provide a level editor.

However, I know you want an editor (who wouldn't). Here is a very new, work-in-progress editor that looks interesting: [3D Scene Editor for XNA](https://sceneeditor.codeplex.com/)

[image: Editor image]

Comment: Yes, it is a good option to save the level, but the most important part for me is to have an editor, even very simple one.

Comment: I agree. I just like this solution because of its beautiful simplicity (no excess info will be stored! And you could use an existing xml parser) and I think projects such as this editor could be fun!

Comment: Actually, I think if I actually have to use UDMF in the end it might be a good idea to write a converter from this format to a simple XML as you suggested.

Comment: @NewProger I have edited my response. I had to find the link for this editor I had stumbled upon a few weeks ago.

Comment: Hm, that is interesting, thank you. But as I understand this editor is for a different type of game, it has terrain and 3D objacts placed on it, while I need something akin to Quake1 levels (enclosed, extruded, levels in empty space) as this is for FPS.

Comment: Sorry, this is such a localized question I am trying to provide solutions. FPSs have not used that technique for quite some time :)

Comment: I understand, but you know... I can't delve into more advanced stuff until I learned the basics, plus I just love the idea of making game engine that would work like that :)

Comment: @NewProger This is not really basics. Simple 3D graphics using the fixed-function pipeline are the basics. The Doom style graphics were because of technical limitations, not because they are "basic." But if you're interested in it, then by all means!

Comment: Yes, you are right, but I just want to work with pure geometry for this project.

Comment: Any graphics are just geometry, trig, and linear algebra :) If you want pure geometry you should look into ray tracing!